# Regex on file name

Tags: regex, typescript, file

I'm having a list of filename and I want to filter them using a regex. I want every file that have the extension `.db.ts` but does not start with a capital `A`.

Here are different situations as example :

**Good**

`/home/foo/file.db.ts`

`/home/anyway.db.ts`

`/home/AExample/anyway.db.ts`

`example.db.ts`

**Bad**

`/home/foo/Afile.db.ts`

`/home/Aanyway.db.ts`

`Aexample.db.ts`

`example.ts`

Here is what I've tried :

```js
const shouldPass = [
  `/home/foo/file.db.ts`,
  `/home/anyway.db.ts`,
  `example.db.ts`,
  `/home/AExample/anyway.db.ts`,
];

const shouldFail = [
  `/home/foo/Afile.db.ts`,
  `/home/Aanyway.db.ts`,
  `Aexample.db.ts`,
  `example.ts`,
];

const regex = /[^A].*\.db\.ts/;

shouldPass.forEach(x => regex.test(x) ?
  console.log(`${x} :: pass`) :
  console.log(`${x} :: not pass`));

shouldFail.forEach(x => regex.test(x) ?
  console.log(`${x} :: not pass`) :
  console.log(`${x} :: pass`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?:.*\/)?[^A][^\/]*\.db\.ts$/
```

Or - to also support file names with no chars before `.db.ts`:

```
/^(?:.*\/)?(?!A)[^\/]*\.db\.ts$/
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/BiOg3n/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/BiOg3n/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*\/)?` - an optional sequence of 0+ chars as many as possible up to the `/`
- `(?!A)` - the next char cannot be `A`
- `[^\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.db\.ts` - `.db.ts`
- `$` - end of string.

See the JS demo below:

```js
const shouldPass = [
  `/home/foo/file.db.ts`,
  `/home/anyway.db.ts`,
  `example.db.ts`,
  `/home/AExample/anyway.db.ts`,
];

const shouldFail = [
  `/home/foo/Afile.db.ts`,
  `/home/Aanyway.db.ts`,
  `Aexample.db.ts`,
  `example.ts`,
];

const regex = /^(?:.*\/)?(?!A)[^\/]*\.db\.ts$/;

shouldPass.forEach(x => regex.test(x) ?
  console.log(`${x} :: pass`) :
  console.log(`${x} :: not pass`));

shouldFail.forEach(x => regex.test(x) ?
  console.log(`${x} :: not pass`) :
  console.log(`${x} :: pass`));
```

Comment: Really good, works well. I havent thought about eliminating all the data left to `/`, it's smart :). I'll accept in few minutes, thanks

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT There should be no `g` flag in the pattern that is used in `.test()`. You [added it to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59307472/4) and I did not remove that, and that is the reason for a downvote, I believe. Note that if you also want to filter out file names that start with lowercase `a` you need to add `i` flag, `/^(?:.*\/)?(?!A)[^\/]*\.db\.ts$/i`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

> /(^(?!A.*$))(?!.*/A.*$).*(.db.ts)$/

```js
    const shouldPass = [
      `/home/foo/file.db.ts`,
      `/home/anyAway.db.ts`,
      `/home/anyway.db.ts`,
      `example.db.ts`,
    ];
    
    const shouldFail = [
      `/home/foo/Afile.db.ts`,
      `/home/anyAway.db.ts.db`,
      `/home/anyAway.db..ts.db`,
      `/home/anyway.db..ts`,
      `/home/AanyAway.db.ts`,
      `/home/anyway.db.Ts`,
      `Aexample.db.ts1`,
      `example.ts1`,
    ];
    
    const regex = /(^(?!A.*$))(?!.*\/A.*$).*(\.db\.ts)$/;
    
    shouldPass.forEach(x => regex.test(x) ?
      console.log(`${x} :: pass`) :
      console.log(`${x} :: not pass`));
    
    shouldFail.forEach(x => regex.test(x) ?
      console.log(`${x} :: pass`) :
      console.log(`${x} :: not pass`));
```

Comment: @grégory-neut provided regex by Wiktor is failing on some success examples 
`/home/anyAway.db.ts :: not pass
example.db.ts :: not pass
` it should pass for these examples right?